# Flutter/ 3 Rows in one Container or AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-alertdialog, flutter-row

I'm trying to make an Alert Dialog with a navigation window. There should be 3 Rows with different IconButtons to Navigate on another site. Unfortunately I'm new to Flutter and don't know how to make 2 more Rows. Can someone please help me? Is it even possible to do that? I mean I can't add any more children or can I? I Don't know if i should split it in 3 AlertDialogs or is that stupid?

[That was my Layout for the first Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONahe.png)

[This is what it should look like but with 3 lines and not two, so that the code that i have right now can be copied to make 3 identical rows parallel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6JkR.png)

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

void popup(BuildContext context) {
  var alertDialog = AlertDialog(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xffb09c84),
    title: Text(''),
    content: Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 300, maxHeight: 600),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      width: 300.0,
      height: 560.0,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: FaIcon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.newspaper,
                  size: 44.0,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 2.0),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  "       Zeitung",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: FaIcon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.envelope,
                  size: 44.0,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 2.0),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  "    News",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: FaIcon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.creativeCommonsSampling,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  size: 44.0,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 3.0,
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  "   Vertretung",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );

  showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => alertDialog);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code now:

```
 Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 300, maxHeight: 600),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      width: 300.0,
      height: 560.0,
      child: //Row(..the rest you want to copy"
```

Add a column before this row, and replicate your `Row` three times:

```
 Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 300, maxHeight: 600),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      width: 300.0,
      height: 560.0,
      child: Column( children: [ 
        Row1("..the rest you want to copy"),
        Row2("..the rest you want to copy"),
        Row3("..the rest you want to copy)" 
     ]), //Column
   ), //Container
```

Comment: First thanks for your help. Can you please explain me exactly what the new Rows mean. I will edit my question because i think i asked wrong.

Comment: Don't mention it, the rows were based on the diagram you posted. Will wait for your update.

Comment: I got it !! I try to finish the 3 Rows and then tell you how it worked out or if i have more problem with this. Thanks so much!

Comment: Great, yes please update regardless! You're welcome anytime.

Comment: Worked out pretty good. Glad you helped me!

Comment: Fantastic, glad you asked!